# Kubernetes deployment connection refused

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to deploy a simple python app to Google Container Engine:

I have created a cluster then run `kubectl create -f deployment.yaml`
It has been created a deployment pod on my cluster. After that i have created a service as: `kubectl create -f deployment.yaml`

> Here's my Yaml configurations:
>
> **pod.yaml**:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-app
spec:
  containers:
  - name: test-ctr
    image: arycloud/flask-svc
    ports:
    - containerPort: 5000
```

> Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:alpine3.7
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD python ./app.py
```

> **deployment.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: test-app
  name: test-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-app
      name: test-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: test-app
        image: arycloud/flask-svc
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: "100m"
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

> **service.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-app
  labels:
    app: test-app
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
    nodePort: 32000
  selector:
    app: test-app
```

> **Ingress**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: frontend
          servicePort: 80
```

It creates a LoadBalancer and provides an external IP, when I open the IP it returns `Connection Refused error`

What's going wrong?

Help me, please!

Thank You,
Abdul

Comment: Hi, Check your targetport and containerport. They are supposed to be same

Comment: Hi @SureshVishnoi, now both ports are same but still returns the same error.

Comment: check security groups for your cluster?

Comment: I have created an ingress controller also  which shows an error as `Some backend services are in UNHEALTHY state`, what did this mean?

Comment: It means the application pod is not up and running

Answer (score 1):

you can first check if the pod is working by `curl podip:port`, in your scenario, should be `curl podip:8080`; if not work well, you have to check if the precess is bind 8080 port in the image you are using.

if it work, then try with service by `curl svcip:svcport`, in your scenario, should be `curl svcip:80`; if not work well, will be a kubernetes networking [congiguration] issue.

if still work, then the issue should be happen on ingress layer.

In theory, it should work if all match the k8s rules.

Comment: Hi @WeiweiJiang, Now I have created a new cluster and simply deploy a pod( added `pod.yaml` in the question) then try to curl it's IP as: `curl http://10.36.2.7:5000/` and also I have added my dockerfile into the question.      But now it returns `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.36.2.7 port 5000: Operation timed out`

Comment: Sometimes the backends are unhealthy and the health check is failing because of the firewall rules. The IP address is the pod IP? Did you open a firewall rule manually?

Answer (score 1):

Your deployment file doesn't have `selector`, it means that the `service` cannot find any pods to redirect the request.

Also, you must match the `conteinerPOrt` on deployment file with `targetPort` in the service file.

I've tested in my lab environment and it works for me:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: test-app
  name: test-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-app
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: test-app
        image: arycloud/flask-svc
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-app
  labels:
    app: test-app
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    app: test-app
```

Answer (score 1):

First make sure your ingress controller in running, to check that `kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx` if you dont find any pods running you need to deploy the kubernetes ingress you can do that by `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml`.

If you have installed ingress controller correctly, then just apply the yaml below, you need to have **selector** in your deployment so that the deployment can manage the replicas, apart from that you dont need to expose a node port as you are going to access your app through load balancer.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-app
  labels:
    app: test-app
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: test-app
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: test-app
  name: test-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-app
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: test-app
        image: arycloud/flask-svc
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: frontend
          servicePort: 80
```